# How do you turn sound off in IRC client colloquy?

Tags: preferences, irc

How do you turn sound off in IRC client colloquy? I don't see any option to do so:

[image]

Comment: @Allan Well, Coloquy is a chat client running on macOSX so questions about it *are* actually on-topic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does this [FAQ](http://colloquy.info/project/wiki/Documentation/UserInterface/Preferences/Alerts) help? It looks like you can use Preferences → Alerts → Mute all notification sounds.

To access Preferences, use the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd>, or select from the Colloquy Menu bar item (just like any other macOS app).

[image]